# Laravel eloquent return both where conditions

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello I have a table `ideas` and I want to return the rows where the user_id = with the authenticated user id plus the rows where category_id = lets suppose is array `[1, 2, 3]`.

Disclaimer: i want both  of the conditions to be returned!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your questions is not clear at all. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - We're here to help you with specific programming problems, not to write code for you. So show us what you've tried so far, share your thoughts with us and we'll help you. But nobody is going to write code for you.

Comment: I didnt askt someone to writte code for me maybe the question is not clear  i just wanted help for that specific part anyway thanks for your time !

Comment: Well as I said, you should edit your question. I don't think that it will get answered.

Comment: I cannot understand what you are trying to ask or say. The best guess here is, look into relationships of users and categories.

Comment: Are you saying that you only want the authenticated user's rows where the category_id is in [1,2,3] Or either the authenticated or the category_ids

Comment: no i want the rows where the user_id = authenticated users plus the rows with the category_id = 1 so if user has created 3 rows and category 1 has 5 rows wich 3 of them are from the same user but 2 of them no i want to be returned 5 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like that:
i think that your table `ideas` and model Idea associated with this have the next structure:
id, user_id, category_id and some other fields...

To get Authenticated user you can do Auth::user();
So, you can do something like this:

```
$categoryIds = [1, 2, 3];
$authUserId = Auth::user()->id;

$ideas = Idea::where('user_id', $authUserId)->whereIn('category_id', $categoryIds)->get();
```

If you need relations to be extracted with the query you can add `with` statement:

```
$ideas = Idea::with('categories')->where('user_id', $authUserId)->whereIn('category_id', $categoryIds)->get();
```

ofc, you need to set realtions in your models

Also you can set relation in user model and get records associated with the user:

```
User.php

public function ideas() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Idea');
}

somewhere in code:

$categoryIds = [1, 2, 3];
Auth()->user()->ideas()->whereIn('category_id', $categoryIds)->get();
```

UPDATE:
To do some form of join you can use this:

```
$userIdeas = Idea::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
$categoryIds = [1, 2, 3];
$categoryIdeas = Idea::where('user_id', '<>', Auth::user()->id)->whereId('category_id', $categoryIds)->get();
$mergedIdeas = $userIdeas->merge($categoryIdeas);
```

AND AT LAST. To do it in one query:

```
$userId = Auth::user()->id;
$categoryIds = [1, 2, 3];
$ideas = Idea::where('user_id', $userId)->orWhere(function($query) use ($categoryIds) {
    $query->where('user_id', '<>', $userId)->whereIn('category_id', $categoryIds);
})->get();
```

Comment: Yes my table is excaclty like that but i alredy have this query and the problem is tha this query is returning only the categories ex. 1, 2, 3 where the user = with the authenticated user i want to be returned all the rows wich belongs to the auth user + the rows wich are in category 1 example

Comment: what means in category 1 example? use where('category_id', 1) ahh seems that i understand. go to use collection. i will update my answer

Comment: so to make it simple i want all the rows wich user created i dont care about the category but because i have a pivot table wich is categories_user and a user belongs to a category i want to be returned and the all his rows plus the the rows wich belongs to category but are not created from him

Comment: Yes i think this will make the trick but i did something like this 

`$ideas = Idea::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->with('user')->with('category')->get();
        $categoriesIdeas = Idea::whereIn('category_id', [1])->where('user_id', '<>', Auth::user()->id)->with('user')->with('category')->get();
        foreach ($categoriesIdeas as $idea) {
            $ideas->push($idea);
        }

        return $ideas;`

Comment: i think there is no other way to make it simpler right ?

Comment: i ended up with 

`$categoryIds = [1];
        return Idea::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->orWhere(function($query) use ($categoryIds) {
            $query->where('user_id', '<>', Auth::user()->id)->whereIn('category_id', $categoryIds);
        })->with('user')->with('category')->get();`

Comment: you can join with like this ->with('user', 'category')

Comment: and if you use only one id you can simple ->where('category_id', $categoryId) (for example, $categoryId == 1 (not array))

Comment: no no it will be an array but in comment i just addet for demostration

Answer (score 1):

Im having a bit of a problem knowing what you want but

If you want the results for authenticated users id and category ids you could

```
$category_ids = [1, 2, 3];
$model->where('category_id', auth()->user->id)->whereIn('user_id', $ids)->get();
```

If you want the results for either the authenticated user or where the category_ids is in the array you could

```
$category_ids = [1,2,3];
$model->orWhere(function($q) use($category_ids) {
    $q->where('category_id', auth()->user->id);
    $q->whereIn('user_id', $category_ids);
})->get();
```

Note that this will break if the user is not authed, but I leave that to you to do.

Comment: im sorry for my bad english ill try to explain it as better as i can so we have 2 users
user1 
user2

and we have 2 categories 
category1
category 2

user 1 has created 5 rows wich 3 of them belongs to category 1 and the other 2 belongs to category 2 

user 2 has created 5 rows wich 2 of them belongs to category 1 and 3 of them to category 2

now user 1 has been authenticated and i want to display him all his rows plus the rows wich are not created from him but belongs to category 1 so as sum there will be returned 7 rows 5 wich are his rows and the other 2 from category 1